# how to see this class CairngormEvent source code?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flexbuilder, swc, cairngorm

```
import com.adobe.cairngorm.control.CairngormEvent;

public class ConfigurationEvent extends CairngormEvent {
```

i can not see this CairngormEvent.swc  i don't know which .swc file could i add in lib?
thanks.

Comment: Why are you using Cairngorm? WHHHHYYYYY?!

Comment: The project is wrritten by our vender, i am new to flash in mobile, i am learning our source code, now i found cairngorm is a mvc framework,
i can't see the project clearly at the begining, now i think i must read the cairngorm firstly.thanks.

Comment: just for extra information, Cairngorm 2 is probably the worst implementation of MVC out there and shouldn't be used if you want to keep your sanity.  There are much better frameworks out there like Parsley and Robotlegs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very obvious what in particular are you asking but I'll try to answer all the possible questions (as far as I can see).

First of all I guess you're using [Cairngorm 2](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/About) in your project.

Ok. In case of absence of Cairngorm library (I mean `Cairngorm.swc`) which contains `CairngormEvent` class you can download it [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Downloads). You need to choose binary package and place it to the `libs` folder of your project.

To have possibility to view class' source code you need to download ZIP archive with sources and attach them to the `Cairngorm.swc`. Just unpack them somewhere first. Then got to the project's properties `> Flex Build Path > Library Path` then select your `Cairngorm.swc`, expand it, select `Source attachment` item and point recently unpacked folder with sources. So now you can press `F3` and navigate sources.

Comment: The project is wrritten by our vender, i am new to flash in mobile, i am learning our source code, now i found cairngorm is a mvc framework,
i can't see the project clearly at the begining, now i think i must read the cairngorm firstly.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are still working with Cairngorm 2.x.x version. You can download the respective swc from below link:

[Cairngorm 2.x downloads](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Downloads)